# Updating character column based on another column in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
df

ID Timestamp Package  Genre Name
1  01        com.abc  NA    NA
1  02        com.xyz  NA    NA
2  04        com.abc  NA    NA
```

Now the Package column has about 1000 unique packages on the basis of which I need to update the Genre and Name columns.

I know how to update these by using vectorized approach or by using within but this means I would have to iterate over all unique package names manually and I was hoping to find a sleeker solution.

Looking at [switch function for column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950809/switch-function-for-column-values) and [R Apply function depending on element in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167756/r-apply-function-depending-on-element-in-a-vector), I was trying to make a switch function that could take in two arguements (package field and Genre field) and use switch statements to update. Not sure if it's the right way to go.

Comment: What is the source of your updates? Are you inputting them manually? Are they in another data structure, perhaps another table? You I would recommend a text editor or a spreadsheet program for manual editing. If you have the other data in a structure use `match` or `merge`, and see the R-FAQ [How to join data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `data.frame` that contains the package information and merge them together on the package.  First drop the genre and name columns as they will be populated with `merge`

```
df[, c("Genre", "Name")] <- NULL

df2 <- data.frame(Package = c("com.abc", "com.xyz"),
                  Genre = c("g1", "g2"),
                  Name = c("n1", "n2"))

merge(df, df2, by = "Package")

  Package ID Timestamp Genre Name
1 com.abc  1         1    g1   n1
2 com.abc  2         4    g1   n1
3 com.xyz  1         2    g2   n2
```